# XSLT Copy child nodes text to parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need help in following xslt code.
I have input as:

```
 <book>
      <book1>
           <name>abc</name>
           <revision>1</revision>
      </book1>
      <book2>
           <name>pqr</name>
           <author>def</author>
      </book2>
 </book>
```

My expected output as:

```
  <book>
      <item>
           <name>book1</name>
           <value>abc1</value>
      </item>
      <item>
           <name>book2</name>
           <value>pqrdef</value>
      </item>
 </book>
```

I have tried fetching value for value node using */text() but i get text only from first child. In future I have many such child elements.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Minakshi

Comment: Please share your XSLT file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet will give you what you want. Even if the child of `boonK` element increase, the template will not need to be change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book/*">
        <item>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </name>
            <value>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </value>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works well. My xslt was similar to yours except for the for each loop. I was thus getting lot of extra spaces which is now resolved. Thanks